# Import matplotlib in python3 failed after successfully installed matplotlib

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, ubuntu-18.04, pydev

After successfully installed matplotlib via the terminal (ubuntu18.04 and VM5.2.44), I could use this package smoothly in python 2.7, but not in python3. I know this should be an environment issue. Could somebody kindly point out how to set up the environment in order for me to use this package (along with some other packages) in both python 2.7  and python3?

Thanks for any suggested details here.

Comment: use `pip3 install matplotlib`  instead of `pip install matplotlib`.

Comment: Problem is solved. Thank you.